# Codeigniter validation always returns false but validation_errors() is empty

Tags: validation, codeigniter-3, my-model-jami

I'm using MY_Model from https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model repository. It uses built in validation library from Codeigniter.

The problem is that validation is always failed in my model. but validation_error() is empty.
this is my rule:

```
protected $validate = [
    [
        'field' => 'text',
        'label' => 'text',
        'rules' => 'required',
    ]
];
```

This is my controller code:

```
$fields = [
    'title'=>'test title',
    'text' => 'message text',
    'user_id_from' => '1',
    'user_id_to' => '1'
];

$this->message_model->insert($fields);
```

And this is how it's used in the library:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->validate);

if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
{
    return $data;
}
else
{
    $this->validation_error = validation_errors();
    return FALSE;
}
```

$this->validation_error is always empty and validation always fails

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a bug in MY_Model library.

When data source type is not "post" validation is skipped.
To enable the library working with "get", add this line to the library just before set_rules method:

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($data);
```

This is expained here:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Comment: this is spam you must use answer for answer no for question.

Comment: I found an answer and answered my own question. What is the problem?

Comment: no problem. You edited your answer also your English is so bad.